# NGINX net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with PM2 ReactJS Frontend and Express Backend in an AWS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nginx, pm2

I have running in an Amazon Web Server a ReactJS Frontend connecting to an Express APIREST. With PM2 to launch both processes and NGINX.

The problem comes when I try to log-in to the app in chrome, the frontend is okay but it refuses to connect to the APIREST.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckvj4.png)

These are the files I have:

APIREST .env

```
DB_CCT=my_db
DB_CCT_USER=user
DB_CCT_PASS=password
DB_CCT_HOST=127.0.0.1
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8017
JWT_SECRET=jotauvedoblete
```

FRONTEND ReactJS .env

I also tried to add the public IP instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 but doesn't work either, it shows the connection timed out.

```
REACT_APP_DB=http://localhost:8017/api/v1/
```

PM2 ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'CCT_REACT',
    cwd: 'cct-web-client/',
    script: 'npm',
 
    // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
    args: 'run start:production',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      PORT: 5001
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      PORT: 5001
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'CCT_API_REST',
    cwd: 'cct_api_rest/',
    script: 'npm',
 
    // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
    args: 'run start',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      PORT: 8017
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      PORT: 8017
    }
  }],
 
  deploy: {
    production: {
    }
  }
}
```

NGINX service

```
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/ubuntu/CCT/cct-web-client/build;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri/ /index.html?q=$uri&$args;
        }

}
```

Comment: Since the frontend is running locally in a browser and sending requests to a remote API on the AWS server, the request must be sent to the _remote_ server's address. `localhost` points to the _local_ machine where the frontend is running, so it's definitely not the correct path to the API.

Comment: Are you getting any response when you try to access the public server's IP on port 80? If it's configured correctly, you should get the default landing page of nginx. This would tell if nginx is configured correctly at least and that the server is actually able to communicate with the outside.

Comment: you are correct but if instead of localhost i add the public ip the error is net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and yes, on port 80 i get the frontend correctly

Comment: That should be the problem to focus on, yes. Using localhost is unfortunately irrelevant. Make sure the Express is actually running by `curl`ing the localhost inside the AWS server’s shell. Also, check `pm2 logs` for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a connection refused, which means that the requests are getting blocked.

I see that you have specified PORT 8017 for your API App, check 2 things -

1. Check in your AWS Security Groups of EC2 Inbound rules for  **PORT 8017** is open for all.
2. Also try to Nginx restart once - `sudo systemctl restart Nginx.
3. For your API, just start your API without pm2 & add a console.log in your route & middleware & make a POST request from POSTMAN to check if your app is working the right way.

Comment: the first two points are done, i just tried the third one and i got connection timed out

Comment: steps to reproduce your issue - 
* stop pm2 for your api
* run node app.js  or  npm start
* add console .log in your port variable in app.use() to check which PORT app is running on.

From AWS point of view , is your API running on Default VPC or Private Subnet ?
* if you have private subnet, you will need to configure application load Balancer & keep PORT 8017 open-for all
* incase of public subnet, try above Steps the issue should be fixed ideally.

Comment: I already tested the port is running on, and its ok. The AWS runs on a private subnet but has a public IP to work with

Answer (score 0):

Allow connect to port 80 on your aws and remove all other and use following nginx config. Also set api backend url in your frontend to your domain or ip on port 80.

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/ubuntu/CCT/cct-web-client/build;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    # Frontend
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # node api reverse proxy
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8017/;
    }
```

}

Also make sure to check first with any api client if you can consume your api without frontend. It should not be timedout.